# Node.js Socket memory leak

Tags: node.js, sockets, memory-leaks, websocket

i'm having a memory leak, but i can't find any error in my code.

Basicallly i'm connecting to 3 diffrent IP's to receive data from them. That works fine 1-2 times. But the 3rd time i always get "ECONNREFUSED" or "data memory leak, 11 data listeners added" errors.

Although i'm closing the socket every time...

Without the if(k==1) logic, the program wouldn't leave the socket.on('data') function... i don't know why either.

```
test[0] =  '10.5.0.11';
test[1] =  '10.5.0.15';
test[2] =  '10.5.0.17';
var x = -1;
var k=0;

function testIP(test) {

  x++;
  if(socket.destroyed == true) {
    socket.connect('2711', test[x], function() {
      socket.write('d\n');
      k=1;
    });
  }

  socket.on('data', function(data) {
     if(k==1) {
       data = data.toString();
       console.log(data);
         if(x<test.length-1) {
          socket.destroy();
          k=0;
          testIP(test);
         }
         else if(x == test.length-1) {
           k=0;
           x=-1;
           socket.destroy();
           setInterval(testIP, 2000, test);

         }
     }
  });
 }
testIP(test);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
socket.setMaxListeners(0);
```

at the beginning of the function solved the Problem ;-)